# How to make double cline in tables?

Tags: tables

I want to draw a double `cline` in a table where the first column is `multirow` 
With double `\hline` I can draw a full double horizontal line but double `\cline{i-j}` seems to have the same effect with single `\cline`.
Is there any other special command to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AFAIK the `\cline` does not add vertical space by itself, therefore the two are just printed over each other. The `booktabs` package, which I can recommend greatly in general for all tables, defines therefore the `\morecmidrules` macro:

```
% \cline is now \cmidrule
\cmidrule{1-2}\morecmidrules\cmidrule{1-2}
```

However, the `booktabs` manual says that double lines are evil and should not be used at all....

Comment: Thanks, good hint but now I have a different problem. 
The vertical lines-borders of the table are broken. Please see the image:
http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/8383/brokentable.png

Comment: @Vasilis: Mmm, I can't tell how to fix that. All what I know is that vertical lines are also considered as evil by the `booktabs` manual ;-) My advice is to avoid them and most horizontal lines. Only do a `\toprule` on top and a `\bottomrule` at the bottom, plus a single `\cmidrule` where you wanted the double rule. This design is new to most people which know tables only from M$ Word, but believe me, it looks better!

Comment: @Vasilis. As Martin says, the table you've linked to should not have vertical lines.

Comment: Indeed it looks better without vertical lines.

Comment: There is however a tradition that double horizontal lines mean summation. So I guess yes they are evil but sometimes tradition is tradition... :)

Answer (score 24):

use package `hhline`, available with any TeX distribution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}\hhline{=~~}
 foo & bar & baz  \\\hhline{~=~}
 foo & bar & baz  \\\hhline{~~=} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simple, and works great! But is there a way to let the vertical lines reach the additional hline? See this example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78851488/Bild1.png
I want the horizontal double line at the bottom to look like the vertical double line in the top part of the picture.

Comment: read the manual of the package `hhline`. There is an example

Answer (score 10):

Put

```
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep
         \vskip-\arrayrulewidth}
```

between `\cline`s.

Comment: That almost works perfectly, except that I have a vertical line on the very left which I would want to stay contiguous (because that is a merged cell).

Comment: Is not it the same as for double `\hline`?  (If so, you are barking at a wrong tree…)

Comment: Maybe it was not clear what I meant. I added an own answer which shows this, and my solution.

Comment: This makes the gap very small. The same spacing as for double `\hline` is achieved by: `\noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth \vskip\doublerulesep}`. The `\arrayrulewidth` is the width of the line and the `\doublerulesep` is the size of the gap between the two lines.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Ilya Zakharevich:

```
... \\ \cline{2-4}
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep
         \vskip-\arrayrulewidth} \cline{2-4}
...
```

results in this for me:
[image: noalign ilya var1]

Note that I have a vertical line on the very left which I would want to stay contiguous, so this is not so nice.

So my solution:

```
... \\ \cline{2-4}
\noalign{\vskip-2\tabcolsep \vskip-3\arrayrulewidth \vskip\doublerulesep}
\\ \cline{2-4}
...
```

This adds another row (`\\`) and then tries to reduce the space of the row (I probably messed up the calculation...).

[image: var2]

I came up with another variant:

```
... \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{4}{|c}{\phantom{x}}
\vspace{-2\tabcolsep}\vspace{-3\arrayrulewidth}\vspace{\doublerulesep}
\\ \cline{2-4}
...
```

Which results in:
[image: var3]

Answer (score 0):

In the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a command `\Hline` which draws horizontal rules excepted in the blocks (created by the command `\Block`). With `\Hline\Hline`, you draw a double horizontal rule which potentially do not extend on the whole array. Moreover, you can use the key `hvlines` to draw all the rules and add `\Hline\Hline` only where you wish.

With Albert's example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines]
$T_{\omega}$ ([sec]) & $T_s$ ([sec]) & Distribution & WER[\%] \\
\Hline\Hline
\Block{6-1}{}
40 (0.4)  & \Block{4-1}{} 5 (0.05) & Uniform & 13.9 \\
          &          & Triangle & 13.8 \\
          &          & Hamming & 13.8 \\
          &          & Gauss $\sigma = 0.4$ & 13.8 \\
\Hline\Hline
          & \Block{2-1}{}4 (0.04) & Uniform & 13.7 \\
          &          & Triangle & 13.7 \\
\Hline\Hline
\Block{3-1}{}
100 (1.0) & \Block{3-1}{}5 (0.05) & Uniform & 13.6 \\
          &          & Hamming & 1.7 \\
          &          & Gauss $\sigma = 0.4$ & 13.7 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).
[image: Output of the above code]