# Dual table alignment and lines

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table that is to big to fit in the page width, thus it is separated into two tables. The truth is that I only use one table but insert an empty row in the middle so that the columns stay aligned. Here's a reduced size example:

[image]

The idea is to removed the double line from the last column in the first row, and the vertical line that separates the last column from the empty column in the second table. The lines are the ones inside the green ellipsis.

The code for the image is:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c | c | r | r | r | r | r}
\multicolumn{2}{}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{NS} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{PV} 
\\
Game Phase & Depth & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Cutoffs} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Re-searches} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Gain}
\\\hline\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Opening} & 8 & 336 & 10 568 & 1 231 & 336 & 0.00
\\
& 12 & 6 871 & 246 028 & 5 520 & 6 871 & 0.00
\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Middle Game} & 8 & 1 605 & 71 728 & 5 532 & 1 605 & 0.00
\\
& 12 & 43 167 & 2 811 969 & 30 219 & 43 167 & 0.00
\\
\multicolumn{7}{}{}
\\
\multicolumn{2}{}{} & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{Two Bounds}
\\
Game Phase & Depth & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Cutoffs} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Re-searches} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Gain}
\\\hline\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Opening} & 8 & 334 & 10 436 & 1 232 & 0.58
\\
& 12 & 6 844 & 244 147 & 5 524 & 0.39
\\\cline{1-6}
\multirow{2}{*}{Middle Game} & 8 & 1 599 & 71 490 & 5 519 & 0.38
\\
& 12 & 42 957 & 2 796 029 & 30 011 & 0.48
\end{tabular}
\caption{example}
\label{tab:example}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Also see [how to make double cline in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/how-to-make-double-cline-in-tables) which references the `booktabs` package that has some useful guidelines for tables.

Answer (score 6):

A better way of doing the table is, of course, with **booktabs** and **siunitx**:

```
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
...
\begin{table}
\newcommand\?{\multicolumn{1}{S[table-format=2.0]}} % just a shortcut
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c *{4}{S[table-format=7.0,group-minimum-digits=4]}
  S[table-format=1.2]}
\toprule
&& \multicolumn{3}{c}{NS} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{PV} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
Game Phase & Depth & \multicolumn{1}{c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\# Cutoffs} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\# Re-searches} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Gain} \\
\midrule
Opening & 8 & 336 & 10 568 & 1 231 & 336 & 0.00 \\
        & 12 & 6 871 & 246 028 & 5 520 & 6 871 & 0.00 \\
\midrule
Middle Game & 8 & 1 605 & 71 728 & 5 532 & 1 605 & 0.00 \\
            & 12 & 43 167 & 2 811 969 & 30 219 & 43 167 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[2ex]
\toprule
&& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Two Bounds} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6}
Game Phase & Depth & \multicolumn{1}{c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\# Cutoffs} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\# Re-searches} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\hidewidth Gain\hidewidth}\\
\midrule
Opening & 8 & 334 & 10 436 & 1 232 & \?{0.58} \\
        & 12 & 6 844 & 244 147 & 5 524 & \?{0.39} \\
\midrule
Middle Game & 8 & 1 599 & 71 490 & 5 519 & \?{0.38} \\
            & 12 & 42 957 & 2 796 029 & 30 011 & \?{0.48} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{An example}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: I love the use of the `booktabs` package, but I'd (i) get rid of the `\bottomrule` and `\toprule` in the middle of the tableau, (ii) replace the `\midrule` commands in the second half of the tableau with `\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-6}` and (iii) replace the final `\bottomrule` command with `\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-6}`. Items (ii) and (iii) are designed to meet the OP's request (green ellipse) -- at least that's how I understood it.

Comment: @Mico I feel that the two rules in the middle help to understand that the table is actually split into two; without them one is led to continue down the columns. I usually say that rules are barriers to stop reading (and that's why vertical rules should not be used). About the `\cmidrule` to cut the last column, it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is this:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c | c | r | r | r | r | r}
\multicolumn{2}{}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{NS} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{PV}
\\
Game Phase & Depth & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Cutoffs} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Re-searches} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Gain}
\\\hline\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Opening} & 8 & 336 & 10 568 & 1 231 & 336 & 0.00
\\
& 12 & 6 871 & 246 028 & 5 520 & 6 871 & 0.00
\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Middle Game} & 8 & 1 605 & 71 728 & 5 532 & 1 605 & 0.00
\\
& 12 & 43 167 & 2 811 969 & 30 219 & 43 167 & 0.00
\\
\multicolumn{7}{}{}
\\
\multicolumn{2}{}{} & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{Two Bounds}
\\
Game Phase & Depth & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Cutoffs} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Re-searches} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{Gain}
\\\hline\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Opening} & 8 & 334 & 10 436 & 1 232 & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{0.58}
\\
& 12 & 6 844 & 244 147 & 5 524 & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{0.39}
\\\cline{1-7}
\multirow{2}{*}{Middle Game} & 8 & 1 599 & 71 490 & 5 519 & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{0.38}
\\
& 12 & 42 957 & 2 796 029 & 30 011 & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{0.48}
\end{tabular}
\caption{example}
\label{tab:example}
\end{table}
```

The difference here is that the last column in the second table will have the same span as the last two columns from the first table.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use `\hhline{<hline spec>}` from the [`hhline` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline). It allows for a very broad range (and better control) of horizontal lines in `array` and `tabular` environments through `<hline spec>`. It controls whether to put a double/single horizontal line, and whether vertical lines should be cut/not across horizontal double lines. In your case, I used `=` for double lines and `:` to cut vertical lines across `=`. Using `hhline` is necessary, since multiple `\cline`s overprint into a single `\cline` by default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c | c | r | r | r | r | r}
\multicolumn{2}{}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{NS} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{PV} 
\\
Game Phase & Depth & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Cutoffs} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Re-searches} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Gain}
\\\hhline{=:=:=:=:=:=:=}
\multirow{2}{*}{Opening} & 8 & 336 & 10 568 & 1 231 & 336 & 0.00
\\
& 12 & 6 871 & 246 028 & 5 520 & 6 871 & 0.00
\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Middle Game} & 8 & 1 605 & 71 728 & 5 532 & 1 605 & 0.00
\\
& 12 & 43 167 & 2 811 969 & 30 219 & 43 167 & 0.00
\\
\multicolumn{7}{}{}
\\
\multicolumn{2}{}{} & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{Two Bounds}
\\
Game Phase & Depth & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TNC} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Cutoffs} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\# Re-searches} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Gain}
\\\hhline{=:=:=:=:=:=~}
\multirow{2}{*}{Opening} & 8 & 334 & 10 436 & 1 232 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{0.58}
\\
& 12 & 6 844 & 244 147 & 5 524 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{0.39}
\\\cline{1-6}
\multirow{2}{*}{Middle Game} & 8 & 1 599 & 71 490 & 5 519 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{0.38}
\\
& 12 & 42 957 & 2 796 029 & 30 011 & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{0.48}
\end{tabular}
\caption{example}
\label{tab:example}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table broken into two with different columns]

Another option might be to turn the table sideways to have more space to put it on a portrait page layout. However, that is a personal preference.