# Remove top corner of a table

Tags: tables

I want to remove the top left corner box of my table, but for now it looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|p{4.1cm}||p{5.5cm}||p{5.5cm}|}
\cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & item 1 & item 2 \\
    \hline \hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    \hline \hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    \hline \hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is there a reason for doubling all interior lines of the table?

Comment: What @Mico said ^. And it looks removed to me, could you post the Output you have and the desired one?

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely clear what you want here. Perhaps you mean that you want the new "outside" borders to be single lines rather than double? As you may have noticed, `\cline` doesn't include any space after it, so [doubling it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/how-to-make-double-cline-in-tables) is ineffective. Of the solutions mentioned in that post, I think the `hhline` package is easiest:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{4.1cm}||p{5.5cm}||p{5.5cm}|}
\hhline{~--}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & item 1 & item 2 \\
    \hhline{-==}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular output]

The [`hhline`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline?lang=en) package also lets you control which lines continue through the intersections and which are broken, in case you actually want distinct boxes rather than connected ones (or want vertical connections as well as horizontal ones).

Answer (score 3):

More or less off-topic :-)

I like to discourage you to design of table as you do in your MWE. Vertical rules  in (accordance with wide spread opinion) should not be used, horizontal lines had to be reduced to minimum etc. For more about professional table settings, please read documentation of `booktabs` package.

Next, don't use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...` for determine table width. It beside natural table width change also font size. Better approach is use for example `tabularx` (which also offer column type `X`, which width is self calculated),  or `tabular*`.

So see, if the following solution is appealing to you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,% for professional looking tables
            tabularx}% for table with determined width

\usepackage{showframe}% for showing page layout
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
some text
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{22mm}% <-- please set width to your wish
                              X X }  % instead of two equal p{...} columns
    \cmidrule[1pt]{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}    & item 1  & item 2    \\
    \midrule[1pt]
                    1   & 2       & 3         \\
                    1   & 2       & 3         \\
                    1   & 2       & 3         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```