# How can I draw double lines only for some of the table cells?

Tags: tables, rules, line

There is a related question: [How can I draw a horizontal line spanning only some of the table cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/how-can-i-draw-a-horizontal-line-spanning-only-some-of-the-table-cells?newreg=2abf53c8862a41cb90a13f6220247120), and I would like to do it for double lines.

**How can I fix my code to draw double lines only for some of the table cells?**

### Issue

There is a command to set a single line, which is `\cline{2-3}`, and `\hline \hline` works to draw double lines for entire table.

It cannot work for set the interval for `\hline{2-3}`, and `\hline \hline` cannot set a specific interval.

### Code

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Foo} & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\hline{2-3}\hline{2-3}
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Bar} & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\cline{2-3}
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/how-to-make-double-cline-in-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|cc|}
        

        \Block{4-1}     {Foo}   & 1 & 2 \\
                                & 1 & 2 \\ \Hline\Hline
                                & 1 & 2 \\
                                & 1 & 2 \\  \Hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Bar}    & 1 & 2 \\
                                & 1 & 2 \\  \cline{2-3}
                                & 1 & 2 \\
                                & 1 & 2\\   \hline

\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite easy with `hhline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Foo} & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\ \hhline{|~|==|}
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Bar} & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\ \hhline{|~|==|}
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]